# Pyspark - How to fetch the latest fileid for the same duplicate file

Tags: sql, postgresql, dataframe, pyspark, record

I have a Files table, where after inserting the values into the table, I need to fetch the fileid from the table and append it to a dataframe and write it to Raw_Tables.

The code works fine for different files, but whenever I am inserting the same file again, it is giving me the first fileid assigned to it rather than the latest one.

Please help me with this

```
insert_query = 'INSERT INTO public."Files" (clientid, filetypeid, filename, filelocation, ' \
                               'filecreatedby, filelastmodifieddate, createddatetime, ' \
                               'lastupdateddatetime, cleintconfigid) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
                ins_values = (
                    src_clientid, src_filetypeid, file_name, src_dir, file_created_by, file_last_modified_date,
                    created_datetime, datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), src_clientfileconfigid,)
                Database().execute_query(insert_query, ins_values)

files_id = \
                    read_postgres('public."Files"').filter((col("filename") == file_name)).select(
                        col("fileid")).collect()[0].asDict()['fileid']
                print(files_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `collect()` returns a list, and then `[0]` will give you the first value. One solution would be to pick up the last element in the list with `[-1]` but it would be safer to order by `createddatetime` (by default it will be ascending order) and then pick the last element in the list.

```py
files_id = read_postgres('public."Files"')\
        .filter((col("filename") == file_name))\
        .select(col("fileid"))\
        .orderBy('createddatetime')\
        .collect()[-1].asDict()['fileid']
```